# Bootstrap form label not appearing in correctlly

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a form-group with inline radio buttons. The issue is that on larger screens the next text input label is appearing right below it on the right side instead of on a new line on the left side.

[image]

I have tried adding line breaks but it didn't help

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
        <br />
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Email
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Phone
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
      <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing">
    </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ag9aqjrz/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order from

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
```

to

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Please use class="row" in <div class="form-group"> outside the div's where u r using class="col-xs-6"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this CSS

```
.form-group .label { display: block }
```

But the best way is to envelope col-* always in a row div.
Here's your code rewritten:

```
<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
        <div>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Email
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Phone
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
          <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

here's my draft to your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ag9aqjrz/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Replace `<br>` with `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

Without using `<br>` and `clearfix` you can try this format

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
          <br>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <label for="optionsRadios1">
          <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="" type="radio">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inline">
            <label for="optionsRadios2">
            <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" type="radio">Phone</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing" type="url">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap every form line into row

```
<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
        <br />
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Email
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Phone
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
      <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n70kLfnc/

Answer (score 1):

Change divs with class="form-group" into "row form-group"

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
                        <br />
                        <div class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Email
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Phone
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  use  for phone number as well as Preferred Contact Method

Phone Number:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is with column structure, as you are mixing "col-sm-x" with "col-xs-x", you should use one of them or both, so the correct version with xs is as follows

```
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="optionsRadios">Preferred Contact Method</label>
                <br />
                <div class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Email
                </div>
                <div class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Phone
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label for="website">Another Text Input:</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Testing">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```